# Cycle2 YouTube plugin not showing correct in iOS8

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, jquery-cycle2

We are having an issue where the jquery cycle2 youtube plugin is not showing full width in iOS 8.  It works fine in iOS 7.  You can even look at the demo site in iOS 8 and see the error - http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/video.php. On the example page if you look at the one with the Videos and Images you can really see it.

Anyone found a solution for this?